# Ajuda para vizualizacao do MegaMenu primefaces

Tags: primefaces, java-ee, menu

Boas colegas, estou com problema em relação ao componente MegaMenu do primefaces gostava que os componentes ficassem visiveis aos usuários mais eles ficam escondidos por tras da regiao central, então gostaria de trazer para frente. Como poderei fazer isso? Tentei usar um css externo e chamar mais infelizmente não resultou então decidi usar css inline também não resoltou. Abaixo deixo imagens

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:form>

        <h3
            style="font-size: 1.3em; margin: 0; margin-left: 2%; font-weight: 1.5; padding: 5px;"
            align="center">Administrador</h3>
        <p:menu style="border:none; width:95%;">


            <p:menuitem icon="ui-icon-check" value="Estoque de produtos"
                outcome="/pages/productos.xhtml" />
            <p:menuitem icon="ui-icon-person" value="Funcionários"
                outcome="/pages/funcionarios.xhtml" />
            <p:menuitem icon="ui-icon-tag" value="Departamentos"
                outcome="/pages/departamentos.xhtml" />


        </p:menu>

        <p:megaMenu orientation="#{MBIncludesBean.orientation}"
            style="border:none;">
            <p:submenu label=" Consultar ações">
            <p:column>
                <p:submenu label="Consultar Historiais">
                    <p:menuitem value="Historial de entradas"
                        outcome="/pages/entradaProductos.xhtml" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Historial de saídas"
                        outcome="/pages/saidaProductos.xhtml" />

                    <p:menuitem value="Historial de requisições"
                        outcome="/pages/requisicoes.xhtml" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Historial de produtos"
                        outcome="/pages/historialProducto.xhtml" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Historial de departamentos"
                        outcome="/pages/historialDepartamento.xhtml" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Historial de funcionários"
                        outcome="/pages/historialFuncionario.xhtml" />
                </p:submenu>
            </p:column>
            </p:submenu>
        </p:megaMenu>
    </h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

codigo CSS

```
@charset "ISO-8859-1";


.ui-layout-west {
    z-index: 20 !important;
    overflow: visible !important;;
}


.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 95% !important;
}

.ui-layout-west .ui-layout-unit-content {
    overflow: visible !important;

}
```

codigo do layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title><ui:insert name="namePage">Layout do sistema</ui:insert></title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"/>




</h:head>
<h:body style="background: #f2f1f1;">
    <p:growl id="msg" life="6000" />


        <p:layout fullPage="true" style="border:none;">

                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="245" style="border:none;" >
                    <ui:insert name="menu" />

                </p:layoutUnit>



                <p:layoutUnit  size="60" position="north"  style="border:none; overflow:visible;">
                    <ui:insert name="cabecalho" />

                </p:layoutUnit>



                <p:layoutUnit position="center"  style="border:none;  ">
                    <ui:insert name="conteudo" />


                </p:layoutUnit>




        </p:layout>


</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: sem código é meio difícil ajudar. Posta o xhtml da sua página aí.

Comment: Sem o código HTML e CSS fica difícil te dar uma resposta precisa, mas vc pode colocar um z-index:100 por exemplo no seu menu para ver se resolve.

Comment: coloquei o Z-index:100 e nao resoltou mas ja adicionei o codigo do menu e css

Comment: Pelo que vi seu problema é com a estrutura do "html", o menu está dentro de um container que tem uma determinada largura e o menu não se expande para além da largura desse container... tem que pensar em uma forma de ajustar isso mas provavelmente vai mudar a estrutura da ordem das tags etc, Se quiser e ninguém apresentar uma solução definitiva posso montar um modelo bem simples pra vc entender o conceito e a ideia da organização do layout, ai vc aplica no seu projeto

Comment: Pode ser, seria uma ajuda para mim @hugocsl, acabei adicionando o codigo do layout do projeto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ayrton como dito no comentário esse é apenas um modelo simples pra te ajudar a entender um modelo de estrutura de html que pode resolver seu problema. Ela basicamente é feita com `position:relative` na `aside` e `position:absolute` na section, com isso vc consegue controlar o `z-index` do `menu` e deixam por cima do conteúdo e sem esse *scrollbar* que aparece ai, pois a `aside` não precisa ter um `width` definido

Tentei economizar no CSS para ficar mais fácil o entendimento, e deixei os comentários no código para vc entender melhor os pontos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que agora o menu abre por cima da section ao lado, mas sem dar barra de rolagem e nem interferir em nada no conteúdo ao seu redor por ter `position:absolute`

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: azure;
}
/* a barra lateral não tem largura definida e está com o z-index definito para sobrepor a section ao lado */
aside {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
/* a section sim tem largura definida em 75% da largura da tela e fica alinhada a direita pois tem um margin-left automático que empurra a section pra direita */
section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: silver;
}

/* CSS apenas para ativar o menu e facilitar a visualização, vc não precisa desse código CSS no seu modelo. */
label {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 500ms;
}
label:hover {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
nav {
  display: none;
}
[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
#btn:checked + nav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <!-- o conteúdo da aside vai ser o seu menu e o restante das infor que precisa. -->
  <label for="btn">menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="btn">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>item 01</li>
      <li>item 02</li>
      <li>item 03</li>
      <li>item 04</li>
      <li>item 05</li>
      <li>item 06</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>

<!-- aqui vem o conteúdo prencipal -->
<section>123</section>
```